# Did Alex Mason kill JFK?

Tags: call-of-duty-black-ops

Is it implied that Alex Mason did kill JFK after the events of Black Ops 1?  Canonically, since Black Ops 2 follows Black Ops 1, I find it weird is nothing is mentioned about JFK in Black Ops 2.

In the final mission Mason confronts Dragovich, saying that the brainwashing Dragovich had attempted to do had failed, but Dragovich seems to remark otherwise "Oh?" & "Tried?".  The final shot of the game, showing a film reel showing the president moving through a crowd with Mason as the final clip implies he was assassinated? Or not?

Comment: I don't think there is an official source saying that he did in fact assassinate him, but it is pretty heavily implied in the game that he did as you've said.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is no concrete yes or no to this question, but as you have mentioned in the question and [@Timmy Jim said in the comments](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/311466/did-alex-mason-kill-jfk#comment442002_311466), the implication is that he *did*, but it is not confirmed anywhere.

However, a scene from Black OPs II seems to insinuate that he did *not* end up killing JFK. From the [wikia](http://callofduty.wikia.com/wiki/Alex_Mason):

> However in 1989, when Mason is talking to Mark McKnight, McKnight asks about his brainwashing and Mason mentions that the Soviets "gave it their best shot", so it is possible that he was not involved in the Kennedy assassination and that his programming failed. Or it suggests that he doesn't remember what happened due to his programming so that Dragovich could have Mason carry out more missions.

Therefore, unless the developers outright say so one way or the other, no one will really know what happened and it is left up to the player's imagination.